# Maperitive rule file

Tags: openstreetmap

I have my osm data and open it in Maperitive.  Map is displaying fine.  I would like to write a rule file for only showing the cycleway and footway.  I use the hiking.mrule file and edit it to only show the cycleway and footway.
After adding my osm data (and the map display fine) I switch to my new hiking.mrule file.  My result is just a grey map screen.  Nothing else. Here is my mrule file:

features

```
lines

    highway footway : highway=footway

    highway cycleway : highway=cycleway
```

properties

```
map-background-color    : #F1EEE8

map-background-opacity  : 1

map-sea-color : #0000FF
```

rules

```
target : footway

    define

        line-color : #FFFF00

        line-width : 5

    draw : line


target : cycleway

    define

        line-color : #808000

        line-width : 5

    draw : line
```

Please let me know if there is any problem with my rule file or way do I just get a grey screen.  Many Thanks

Comment: Does [other existing rules](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Category:Maperitive/Rules) work fine? You followed the instructions on [altering the style](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive#Changing_the_Rendering_Rules)?

Comment: yes, i alter the hiking.mrule style, because when I create my own rule, which looks the same as above, Maperitive gives me the following error: could not find a part of the path